# Encode to ProRes 4444 with GStreamer vtenc_prores

Tags: gstreamer

The [`vtenc_prores` encoder](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/applemedia/vtenc_prores.html?gi-language=c) in GStreamer supports changing the ProRes variant:

```
Pad Templates:
  ...
  SRC template: 'src'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      video/x-prores
                     ...
                variant: { (string)standard, (string)4444xq, (string)4444, (string)hq, (string)lt, (string)proxy }
```

However I'm unclear how to switch to the ProRes 4444 variant in my pipeline:

```
appsrc name=src emit-signals=True
! videoconvert
! vtenc_prores quality=1.0
! qtmux
! filesink location=output.mov
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I should do the following:

```
 ! vtenc_prores quality=1.0
+! video/x-prores,variant=(string)4444
 ! qtmux
```

This adds a [caps filter](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/gstreamer-tools.html?gi-language=c#caps-filters) to explicitly customize how the `src` on the `vtenc_prores` element gets hooked up to the `qtmux` element.

It's important to use `(string)` there because otherwise 4444 will be interpreted as an integer and cause an error (even if you put it in quotation marks).